# How can I retrieve the g-recaptcha-response value?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, recaptcha

Been trying to mess with Recaptcha and web scraping recently.

Just want to ask how can I fetch the g-recaptcha-response value from a invisible Recaptcha box that is replaced with a submit button.
eg:

```
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/reload?k=6Lfz-q8jAAAAAP7m7TRTJQ_oS2NHwH-v54Ku-ecF
```

I found out that upon sending a POST request to this link, [it also sending a data that is encrypted with x-protobuffer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBusD.png)

So my question would be how can I found the payload data / fetch the g-recaptcha-response directly?

Here's what I've tried:

```
from fake_headers import Headers
from pypasser import reCaptchaV3
from requests_html import HTMLSession

def get_random_headers():
  header = Headers(
    browser="chrome",
    os="win",
    headers=True
  )
  return header.generate()

params = {
    ":authority": "www.google.com",
    ":method": "POST",
    ":path": "/recaptcha/api2/reload?k=6Lfz-q8jAAAAAP7m7TRTJQ_oS2NHwH-v54Ku-ecF",
    ":scheme": "https",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    "Content-Length": "8972",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-protobuffer",
    "Origin": "https://www.google.com",
    "Referer": "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&k=6Lfz-q8jAAAAAP7m7TRTJQ_oS2NHwH-v54Ku-ecF&co=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZXhpdGxhZy5jb206NDQz&hl=en&v=lLirU0na9roYU3wDDisGJEVT&size=invisible&cb=fbb37hv3971m",
    "Sec-Ch-Ua": '"Chromium";v="118", "Brave";v="118", "Not=A?Brand";v="99"',
    "Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile": "?0",
    "Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform": '"Windows"',
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
    "Sec-Gpc": "1",
    "User-Agent": f"{get_random_headers()["User-Agent"]}"
}

exl = reCaptchaV3("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&k=6Lfz-q8jAAAAAP7m7TRTJQ_oS2NHwH-v54Ku-ecF&co=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZXhpdGxhZy5jb206NDQz&hl=en&v=MydHw_zggsxIJuhSbyOmPv5R&size=invisible&cb=n9ml8si5d1xw")

request = HTMLSession()
r = request.post("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/reload?k=6Lfz-q8jAAAAAP7m7TRTJQ_oS2NHwH-v54Ku-ecF", params=params)
```

Without the payload, I would only get a response:

`)]}'["rresp",null,null,null,null,null,1]`